# PostgreSQL doesn't close connections

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

We are using Liferay Portal 5.2.3 (with Hibernate and C3P0) on Tomcat 5.5.27, PostgreSQL 8.3.
Normally, c3p0 pools connections and return it for reusing. But sometimes we need a lot of updates in time and postgreSQL doesn't release connection after closing (we can see 100 IDLE connections). Also, that problem reproduces only on Linux (Debian 5.0).
Connections are establing by independent threads, and in the finally block of run() method we're always close it.
I've tried do not use pool and wrote simple DBConnection manager (getConnection() -> runQuery() -> closeConnection()), but PostgreSQL didn't release it.

Comment: does having those idle connections cause a problem? Check the c3p0 documentation for how to set the maximum number of idle connections.

Comment: Yes, it's a BIG problem - we got an error 'too many users already' (and we can't increase coonections number to infinity). I played with c3p0 settings - it calls connection.close(), but on the Postgre side it still idle process. As I mentioned, I've also tried use it without c3p0.

Comment: Please asnwer this question if you found the solution, it sounds like an interesting problem.

Comment: "*PostgreSQL doesn't release connection*". That is correct. The **client** must release the connection. If your connections aren't closed, there is something wrong with your application, not the server.

Comment: I call connection.close(), but it still occupied on server. As I know, PostgreSQL return it to own pool for reusing, but when I make new connection, postgre doesn't take it from pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

huh... It was problem in code (one *bad guy* didn't close connections)

Comment: Any hints on tracking down these kinds of problems?

Comment: I manually checked all places when we connected to DB. And in some of them the're wasn't call to close() method.